# Deleted a user but forgot to delete home directory and user files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, files, rhel

I have deleted a user using userdel command, but I forgot to delete user files. Now I want to delete those files, how can I find and delete them?

Comment: I assume that you mean that you didn't use `-r` with `userdel`? That would only remove the user's home directory, so that's easy to do manually. Finding anything else on the system belonging to the user is a matter of using `find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ways of finding the userid they used to have (for example because you have one file/directory you know they owned, like their home directory), you can use

```
find / -uid (userid)
```

to find all files owned by that user id. You could use `find / -uid (userid) -delete` to delete them all, but I strongly advise against it without first reviewing what you'd delete. (In all likelihood, it's just their home directory plus some stuff in `/tmp`.)

If you have no way of finding their userid, you can use

```
find / -nouser
```

to find all files belonging to users that don't exist in the system anymore and take an educated guess from the result about file they owned.

Comment: using `-user` instead of `-uid` would be portable.  The `-user` predicate for `find` accepts numerical UIDs too. Also note that you may want to look for files belonging to the user's primary GID as well.

Answer (score -1):

`userdel -r deletedUser` and then you cant run `find / -iname deletedUser` to be sure.

Comment: `find -iname deletedUser ` would look for files and directories whose name is `deletedUser` (case-insensitive). Was this was this what you intended? Would it not be better to to use `-user` and/or `-group` with the numerical UID and GID of the user?

Comment: Yes   , but  when the user is deleted ,  'find -user' doesn`t work . Nevertheless when  you run 'userdel -r '  with the deleted user deletes everything .My example only displays files like /home /mail

Comment: It would work if you used the UID rather than the username I believe.